# Global button for jquery tabs form

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-tabs

I am looking if this can be accomplished via css and jqueryUI and/or jquery
I would like to break up a form into tabs where the user can enter information, and I'd like to have a set of buttons, update, cancel..etc on the page regardless of what tab the user is in he/she can click on.

Thanks and sorry if this is a basic question, but I looked around and could not find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

You should be able to put whatever controls you want on each tab.

You can place the common controls below the tabbed UI control.

Comment: Thanks, but perhaps I was not clear about what my question is. I have the form in the tabs and I can click on each tab without a problem.
My question is, how can I have a save or cancel button, outside of the tabs, that is a button that regardless of what tab the user is looking at he/she can press the button and update or cancel the updates. 
Please let me know if I'm not being clear on what my question is.

Thanks

Comment: If you place button outside the tab control, and then use jQuery to provide an event handler that operates on the form (i.e., the buttons drive the submit) then that should work.  If each tab has a form, then you will need to see which tab is active in order to submit the proper form.